# Disable input button when field.value is empty

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've seen this answered in jquery, but I'd like to know how I can do it in javascript. So far I came up with the following, but I understand it is not capturing the nameF.value properly.

```js
var nameF = document.getElementById("name-field");

var formButton = document.getElementById("form-button");

function go() {
  if (nameF.value == "") {
    formButton.classList.add("notclickable");
  }
}

go();
```

```css
#form-button {
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  font-family: $body-font;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 800;
  background-color: #000;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 2px;
  opacity: 1;
}

#form-button.notclickable {
  opacity: .1;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="name" class="form-style form-field" id="name-field" placeholder="Your name">
<input type="submit" value="Send" id="form-button">
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask#
```

How can I do it without jQuery, just using vanilla?

Thank you!

Comment: Depends on behavior you are looking for. You only call `go()` once when page loads and before user does any input

Comment: `.keyup` event toggle the `disabled` attribute on the `button` element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need is an event handler assigned to `nameF`, and to `.toggle()` the class instead of `add()`.

The `.toggle()` receives an optional second argument where you tell it if it should add or remove the class, so you'll pass the string comparison there.

```js
var nameF = document.getElementById("name-field");

var formButton = document.getElementById("form-button");

function go() {
  formButton.classList.toggle("notclickable", nameF.value == "");
}

go();

nameF.addEventListener("input", go);
```

```css
#form-button {
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  font-family: $body-font;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 800;
  background-color: #000;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 2px;
  opacity: 1;
}

#form-button.notclickable {
  opacity: .1;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="name" class="form-style form-field" id="name-field" placeholder="Your name">
<input type="submit" value="Send" id="form-button"> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask#
```

Also, be aware that you don't need a class to disable the button. You can use the `disabled` property with the `:disabled` selector. This disables its functionality too instead of just fading it.

```js
var nameF = document.getElementById("name-field");

var formButton = document.getElementById("form-button");

function go() {
  formButton.disabled = nameF.value == "";
}

go();

nameF.addEventListener("input", go);
```

```css
#form-button {
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  font-family: $body-font;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 800;
  background-color: #000;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

#form-button:disabled {
  opacity: .1;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="name" class="form-style form-field" id="name-field" placeholder="Your name">
<input type="submit" value="Send" id="form-button"> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask#
```

Comment: Thank you rock star! I was unaware of the "input" event. Worked perfectly. :)

Comment: You're welcome. Just be aware that it is somewhat newer compared to events like `keypress`. Still, all modern browsers do support it.

Comment: By the way, I cannot seem to understand what the `=` means in

`formButton.disabled = nameF.value == "";`

How does it work? Could you translate to current language what this is _saying_?

Comment: The `=` is simply the assignment operator. So the `nameF.value == ""` produces either `true` or `false`, and that value gets assigned to the `.disabled` property.

Comment: oh I see! but wouldn't it also work if I used a if (nameF.value == "") {formButton.disabled} ? I tried the if case, and it did not work.

Comment: That doesn't work because you need to *modify* the value of the `.disabled` property in order for the DOM to get updated. So to do it using an `if` statement, you'd need `if (nameF == "") { formButton.disabled = true } else { formButton.disabled = false }`

Comment: lol now I used 

`function makeClickable() {
        if (nameF.value == "") {
            formButton.disabled = true;
        } else {
            formButton.disabled = false;
        }
    }`

and it worked! thank you :P

Answer (score 1):

Try something like that!

```js
var nameF = document.getElementById("name-field");

var formButton = document.getElementById("form-button");

function onChangeContent(e) {
  formButton.disabled = e.target.value !== '' ? false : true;
}

nameF.addEventListener('keyup', onChangeContent);
```

```html
<input type="text" name="name" class="form-style form-field" id="name-field" placeholder="Your name">
<input type="submit" value="Send" id="form-button" disabled>
```